# How to get files from SFTP using TSQL or SQL Server Agent?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sftp

I need to get files from SFTP and stored them on server. Is there any way I can do that using TSQL or SQL Server Agent? I do not want to use Third party tools or SSIS or PowerShell Script or WinSCP.

Comment: this article might help: http://www.itworld.com/article/2847292/how-to-fetch-a-file-from-ftp-and-import-into-sql-server-automatically.html

Comment: Write a [CLR Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). AFAICT there is no built in way to do this in pure T-SQL or with any special functionality in SQL Agent.

Comment: I know you said don't but I use WinSCP and make the call from SQL Server Agent Job.

Comment: @SQLChao : any example using winSCP from SQL Agent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install WinSCP. In my environment it is on the SQL Server we are frequently sending from.

Then you need to create a text file that script the commands. The inside of this file will look like

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://Username:Password@someftp.someftp.com -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 29:fd:bb:27:3z:f0:28:b0:58:8g:07:59:b8:21:19:c4"
put D:\exports\*.csv
exit
```

For more information on WinSCP Scripting you can go **[HERE](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting)**

Next create a job and in the step make it type `Operating system (CmdExec)`. In the command section call the location of Winscp.exe and pass as an argument the path to the script file you made in the previous step.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe /script=d:\exports\sftp.txt
```